# Access child methods via parent class using this in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Given class A and class B, where class B inherits from class A ...

```
// Define class A
dojo.declare("mynamespace.A",null,{
    myMethodA: function() { this.myMethodB() }
});

// Define class B
dojo.declare("mynamespace.B",mynamespace.A,{
    myMethodB: function() {}
});
```

Is it legal to call this.myMethodB() in the scope of class A (parent class)?
I have seen this in a piece of software and I do not understand it. I know that in Java, this is not possible unless you typecast A to B. But is dojo any different?

Comment: Technically it is possible of course. The language does not prohibit this.

Comment: there are plans with AMD patterns to hide the global declarations, i.e. we will need to pull in dependency and reference by local variable instead og global (pollutable) scope. check if you have access to required modules via dojo.has("config-publishRequireResults"). It is still, currently the default behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buzzword of this question would be **this.inherited(arguments);**
Your question goes for calling a method which is not in the current inheritance scope - and would by a true object oriented programmer be called invalid.. However it is possible (still) since the loader declared everything in global scope, e.g. you can access any module via *mynamespace.X and then add prototype.theMethod.*

Once you have inheritance as in mynamespace.B all of the functionalities of both A and B are 'this' scoped. It is simply like a merged hash of stuff, say `for all methods and variables in A do set instance B[key] = property A[key]`.

However if you would encounter an override where the property is prototyped for both 'class' A and B - there is a mechanism in the declare / construct chain which allows for calling 'super' (or parent class, following your notation).

For the special property constructor it is allways so, that the inheritance bubbles[period].

For any methods that are declared only once, you cannot with respect of yourself call it if it is not an inherited method - and it will then be accessible via 'this'

For any methods which have overrides, the function 'this.inherited(arguments);' will send you upwards, one tick to the current parent class of callee. Look at the extended fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/seeds/FW8CW/1/)

```
var AClass = dojo.declare("mynamespace.A", null, {
    constructor: function(args) {
        this.overriddenMethod();
    },
    overriddenMethod: function() {

    }
});
var BClass = dojo.declare("mynamespace.B", [AClass], {

    constructor: function() {  },

    overriddenMethod: function() {
        // call super before anything else is processed in this method
        // by placing following call you can control function callflow
        this.inherited(arguments);
    }
});

// will call A.constructor, then A.overriddenMethod
new AClass();

// will call B.constructor, A.constructor, B.overriddenMethod and then
//  A.overriddenMethod via the call to super
//  in B.overriddenMethod which A.constructor 
//  calls (note that A.constructor callflow 'aims' B.override not A.override)
new BClass();
```

Comment: btw, with regards to static userspace i tend to use this form: `var AClass = declare(.,.,{ constructor: ... }); AClass.ENUMA = 0; ...`

Answer (score 1):

There is no static compilation in JavaScript, therefore, as @akonsu has mentioned yet, it is technically possible, but it's not a pattern to follow:

```
var a = new mynamespace.A();
a.myMethodA(); // ilegal: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'methodB' 

var b = new mynamespace.B();
b.myMethodA() // legal
```

You can also execute method/function in a given scope in JavaScript, i.e. as a method of given object:

```
a.myMethodA.call(b); // legal as `this` inside `myMethodA` will be referencing to object `b`
```

Practically, I think `mynamespace.A` may emulate abstract class with abstract method `myMethodB` as you know it from Java. Class `mynamespace.A` when subclassed, the subclass should implement `myMethodB`. But doing it this way is very error prone and I would do it in a more robust manner:

```
// Define class A
dojo.declare("mynamespaca.A", null, {

    myMethodA: function() {
        this.myMethodB();
    },

    myMethodB: function() {
        // abstract method
        console.warn("Abstract method [myMethodB] was not implemented.");
        // or: throw new Error("Abstract method [myMethodB] was not implemented.");
    }   

});


// Define class B
dojo.declare("mynamespace.B", mynamespace.A, {

    myMethodB: function() {
        // implement abstract method here
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call any method using the prototype object.

```
myMethodA: function() { mynamespace.B.prototype.myMethodB(); }
```

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/7cBJm/